# If a client continues to send data after I close a TCP connection, will it have a negative impact on the performance of my server?

Tags: networking, tcp

Say a client opened a TCP connection to my server. We send some data back and forth, and eventually my server closes the connection. However, due to a bug in the client's software (perhaps at a low level), it doesn't realize the connection has been closed and continues to try to send data to the server.

How much of a performance impact will this have on my server?

Comment: Is it trying to send the data with the pre-existing session, or does it re-establish or try to establish a new TCP connection and does your server permit it to do so?  I agree with Michael Hampton's answer but wonder if the client is "taking the hint" or not.  (This is more for debugging their software, I guess)

Comment: Are we talking about a TCP stack bug or an application bug?

Answer (score 4):

Very little impact on performance, though it will consume bandwidth.

IF the traffic reaches your server, it'll just get rejected out of hand since it doesn't correspond to an open connection.

Your edge firewall may also drop it for you, since it doesn't correspond to an open connection.

Comment: +1 for edge firewall.